# Wordpress Elementor custom query with array of taxonomy terms - how to require all terms are in returned posts

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, taxonomy-terms

I am so close and this one thing is not working. Appreciate any help though I'm beginning to think this might be a limitation of Wordpress?

This is for a related products area on a custom post type page. The post and the products on this site both use the 'models' taxonomy and each post often uses several terms in that tax. So, when on a post page with certain terms, we want to show products in particular (default woocommerce) categories that also have ALL of the same 'models' taxonomy terms as the current post.

So, I have the code below working except that it is not returning products that have ALL of the terms in the $tax_slugs array. It's returning all products that have ANY of the terms. If I include the 'AND' operator in the nested array, it returns nothing.

Hope this makes sense. Thank you!

**1st Try**

```
add_action( 'elementor/query/model_loop_free', function( $query ) {
//get ID of current post
$id = get_queried_object_id();
// get current taxonomy - in this case the make/model
$taxos = get_the_terms( $id, 'models');
foreach ( $taxos as $tax ) {
        $tax_slugs[] = $tax->slug;
    }
$tax_query = array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'models',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => $tax_slugs,
        //'operator' => 'AND'
    ),
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => 'free-play-adapter'
    ),
);

$query->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
} );
```

Using the above code, $tax_slugs returns this format:
Array ( [0] => m100c [1] => seeburg )

**2nd Try** I also tried a different approach which returns no product posts at all whether I use the operator or not:

```
add_action( 'elementor/query/model_loop_free', function( $query ) {
$id = get_queried_object_id();
$taxos = get_the_terms( $id, 'models'); 
// convert array of term objects to array of term slugs
$tax_array = array();
foreach ( $taxos as $tax ) {
        array_push($tax_array,$tax->slug);
    }
$tax_slugs = "'" . implode("','", $tax_array) . "'";
    $tax_query = array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'models',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $tax_slugs,
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'free-play-adapter',
        ),
    );

$query->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
} );
```

Using the above code, $tax_slugs returns in this format:
'm100c','seeburg'

**3rd Try** And, my final, pseudocode attempt (maybe?) in trying to create each term as a separate nested array returns ANY of the terms but not ALL:

```
add_action( 'elementor/query/model_loop_free', function( $query ) {
$id = get_queried_object_id();
$taxos = get_the_terms( $id, 'models'); 
foreach ( $taxos as $tax ) {
        $tax_slugs[] = array(
        "'taxonomy' => 'models',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => '" .$tax->slug. "',
        'operator' => 'AND'"
    );
    }
    $tax_query = array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array($tax_slugs),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'free-play-adapter',
        ),
    );

$query->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );

} );
```

Using the above code, $tax_slugs returns in this format:
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 'taxonomy' => 'models', 'field' => 'slug', 'terms' => 'm100c' ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 'taxonomy' => 'models', 'field' => 'slug', 'terms' => 'seeburg' ) )

Comment: Have you checked what `$tax_slugs` actually contains? I can't see your `wp_list_pluck` call there make much sense, the second parameter is supposed to be an integer or a string, identifying which field your want to pluck from the objects you pass in. Why are you passing the _slug_ of the currently queried object for that?

Comment: @CBroe - thanks, I tested the $tax_slugs and it was not returning just the terms from the current post so I have updated the code above to use a method that only return the terms matching the current post. Now I still cannot get it to show other posts with ALL matching terms rather than with ANY. If I include the operator => AND it returns no posts at all when there should be one on my test page. Without that operator it returns all posts matching any of the matching terms.

Does it matter whether I use slug or ID?

Comment: have you tried using the IDs instead of the slugs? No idea if it works, just a guess from https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/138270/178

Comment: Yes, @hakre I have tried using the IDs with the same results. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you need to use the AND relation, but for it to work as you want, you need to add several conditions inside the tax_query, not a single one with all the tags.
Plus you have two distincts conditions: one for the product_cat, and one for one (or several "models").

You can set all the parameters at the same level or as subquery, as tax_query accept nested conditions (like subquery in SQL).

In order to group related conditions together, I'll use sub query here.

Here is a pseudo code to explain it more visualy:

```
// tax_query
$tax_query = [
    'relation'  =>  'AND', // this relation is between the product_cat and the models
    [], // condition relative to the product_cat
    // the sub query containing all models
    [
        'relation'  =>  'AND', // this relation is for the models between each other
        [], // condition one (ex: model 1)
        [], // condition two (ex: model 2)
        [], // condition three (ex: model 3)
        //...   
    ] 
];
```

So your code would looks like this:

```
add_action( 'elementor/query/model_loop_free', function ( $query ) {
    // get current product id
    $product_id = get_queried_object_id();

    //get current product's models
    $taxos = get_the_terms( $product_id, 'models'); 
    
    // Initial tax query (limit to the specific product_cat)
    $tax_query = [
        'relation' => 'AND',
        [
            'taxonomy'  => 'product_cat',
            'field'     => 'slug',
            'terms'     => 'free-play-adapter'
        ]
    ];
    
    // Generate sub tax parameters (all models)
    $sub_tax_query = [
        'relation'  =>  'AND'
    ];
    // Add one condition per "model"
    foreach ( $taxos as $tax ) {
        $sub_tax_query[] = [
            'taxonomy'  =>  'models',
            'field'     =>  'slug',
            'terms'     =>  $tax->slug
        ];
    }

    // Inject sub query (models) as the second condition to the main tax_query
    $tax_query[] = $sub_tax_query;

    // Add finnaly inject tax_query to query
    $query->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
} );
```

Comment: Duuuuuuude! If we were in the same room you'd be getting a big ole non-consensual hug right now. Thank you so much!